# list all primary key constraints by name, not system name

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008

I want to list all of the primary key constraints in a database. The information I need is

- constraint name
- table.column(s) of the key
- Ordinal Position of the column in the key

For the constraint name I need the name and not the system generated name.

Does anyone have a query out there that does that?

Thanks in advance,

Comment: I'm not sure what distinction you're drawing between the "name" and the "system generated name" - the only system generated names I'm aware of are the ones that are produced if the constraint was added *without* a name - so there's no situation where a constraint will have both a "name" and a "system generated name". Can you give an example of what you mean?

Comment: I need to compare primary key constraints between two databases. With the system generated constraint names it's not possible because the constraint name will be different on each db. Is there another way I can reference a constraint in a way that will allow me to compare them across data bases?

Comment: Then surely you should just be comparing based on the *table* name, not the *constraint* name - since each table can only have one PK.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, Damien_The_Unbeliever is correct I should not be comparing base on constraint name, instead I should be comparing based on table.column name.

Answer (score 0):

How about:

```
SELECT kcu.CONSTRAINT_NAME, 
    kcu.TABLE_NAME, 
    kcu.COLUMN_NAME, 
    kcu.ORDINAL_POSITION  
FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.TABLE_CONSTRAINTS pk
    JOIN  INFORMATION_SCHEMA.KEY_COLUMN_USAGE kcu 
        ON kcu.CONSTRAINT_NAME = pk.CONSTRAINT_NAME
    WHERE pk.CONSTRAINT_TYPE = 'PRIMARY KEY'
```